# Visual Studio 2022 CMake Presets

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, cmake-presets

I'm using CMake in my project and I'm beginning to explore the possibilities of CMakePresets

I managed to create a default windows preset. Currently my Windows default preset sets the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to debug.
now I'd like to select the config in the left drop-down and the Build Type in the right drop-down (see image)

Is this somehow possible?

Thx for your help

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just understanding this myself, but I believe what you want is to set up "buildPresets" like so:

```json
{
   "name": "windows-debug",
   "displayName": "Debug",
   "configurePreset": "windows-default",
   "configuration": "Debug"
},
{
   "name": "windows-release",
   "displayName": "Release",
   "configurePreset": "windows-default",
   "configuration": "Release"
}
```

I believe "configuration" should be used instead of `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` as its identical to the flag `--config` as in

```
> cmake --build . --config Release
```

Source: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html#build-preset